# Saving a value in a var forever?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there anyway to save a `var` value forever?

Let´s say I have this:

```
private var b:int;

private var xb:int;



public function UPD()
{
    start();
}

private function start():void 
{
    //add a button to do something
    //add a button to do whatever
}

//define the listener for the buttons (MouseEvent.CLICK, something & MouseEvent.CLICK, whatever)

private function something(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if (!b){b = (1 + xb);}
    //another function to do something else after adding b + xb
}

private function whatever(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    xb++
}
```

This way `xb` (and `b`) will have 1 more each time I click on the whatever button...now let's say I close everything...how can I have the values I had before, back, when I open it again, so `xb` doesn´t start from `0` again, but it keeps the clicks from previous time?

Answer (score 1):

You need to incorporate some means of external storage for the values such that you can retrieve them when you come back to the program after having closed and reopened it. This could take the form of storing the data in a database (MySQL), or a data file (text/xml), or as a SharedObject (Flash version of a cookie).

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value in a shared object (which is basically like a cookie but for flash): http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html.

On startup, you can retrieve the value, and every time it changes, you can save it back into the SharedObject again. This doesn't propagate through multiple clients, however. (So each client will have a different count)